# Will Exchange DAG copy unstable/corrupt database changes?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, dag

We just set up a DAG environment between 2 Exchange Servers.

One of the servers hosts the active databases and one hosts passive copies (no lagtime).

I think this will work perfectly in the case of a hardware failure but I'm worried about the application-side of things.

If our active mailbox database gets corrupted (maybe due to missing log files or a corrupted EDB) won't the secondary server just replicate the "corruption" of the EDB file into the passive copy?

Or is DAG smart enough to realize when and/or what causes the corruption in the active database and stop replicating those faulty settings to the passive copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate here between Logical and Physical corruption:

*Physical corruption:*

Will occur when the database from an ESE structure is no longer valid in some way. Those corruption couldn´t replicate. Its simply not possible by Microsoft design (Exchange performs multiple steps to validate the logfiles; more infos [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb891802(v=exchg.150).aspx)). So if the structure from an ESE perspective is no longer valid (e.g. “Dirty Shutdown” due to a hardware failure) you couldn´t bring the EDB online.

*Logical corruption:*

Will occur when the data within the database is no longer valid, but the structure from an ESE perspective is valid. Those corruption can replicate (but will also occur in a stand alone Exchange server). However you have different ways to deal with them:

- You can move the mailbox, thereby deleting the bad data. Useful, especially when logical corruption occurred outside the backup retention window. (Check the baditemlimit options, more info's [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mikehall/2013/08/06/managing-failed-mailbox-move-requests/))
- You can implement and use single item recovery and restore the original item. Useful when editing message caused corruption (client app caused corruption scenario).
- You can use the Calendar Repair Assistant to detect and correct inconsistencies (Since Exchange 2010 SP2) See more info's [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633473(v=exchg.141).aspx).
- You can use [New-MailboxRepairRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625226(v=exchg.160).aspx) which can address corruptions with search folders, item counts, folder views, and parent/child folder issues (See more info's [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625221(v=exchg.141).aspx) and [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/212-fix-a-corroupt-microsoft-exchange-mailbox-database.html)).
- You can maintain an Exchange backup (VSS backup or lagged copy if backup retention window is between 0 and 14 days) (See [here](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/exchange-server-database-corruption-and-dirty-shutdown-scenarios/) for more infos).

**Conclusion:**

A DAG will not help you really to avoid corrupt elements inside the mailbox. But without a DAG you will also have those corrupt elements and need to deal with them anyway. And if one node (during startup) discover that the EDB is corrupt, it will not bring it up (e.g. its in a “Dirty Shutdown”). You need to fix the issue here (e.g. you can create a new DB copy, more other options can be seen [here](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/exchange-server-database-corruption-and-dirty-shutdown-scenarios/)).

Comment: Thanks a lot, BastianW! Informative & helpful answer. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If our active mailbox database gets corrupted, DAG will replicate the "corruption" of the EDB file into the passive copy as well. DAG is not designed to automatically detect and prevent the replication of corrupted data.

For this you should have proper monitoring and safeguards in place to prevent replication of corrupted data. This includes

-Monitoring for database corruption on the active copy

-Regularly perform database health checks

-Ensuring regular backups

-Maintaining a sufficient number of log files for recovery

-Use Exchange built-in tools for integrity checks

So if corruption is detected on the active database, you should take immediate action to resolve it. You can check this article [Reseed after Mailbox Database Copy Failed and Suspended](https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/reseed-a-failed-database-copy-in-exchange-server.php).

**Important Tip-** Exchange logs can provide insights into the health of your database copies. Analyzing these logs can help you identify and address issues promptly.